# Glassfish 3 stand-alone client hangs during ejb lookup

Tags: java, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

Per this guide http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gkusn.html#gkusp I am trying to access an ejb component from a remote stand-alone client.  When executing my remote client, I have the gf-client.jar on the classpath, and included the jvm properties

```
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=<remoteHost>
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700
```

However, when my code does the lookup of the bean, it hangs, no exceptions thrown.  On the remote machine running Glassfish, I can do a netstat and see an established connection from my client machine to port 3700.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT:
Not sure where the exception was being swallowed, but I was able to run it in my IDE and I get this exception thrown on the lookup, after which the client hangs.

```
org.jvnet.hk2.component.ComponentException: injection failed on org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.invHandlers with class [Lorg.glassfish.api.invocation.ComponentInvocationHandler;
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.error_injectionException(InjectionManager.java:284)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:161)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:93)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByContract(Habitat.java:1050)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getComponent(Habitat.java:779)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecurityMechanismSelector.postConstruct(SecurityMechanismSelector.java:166)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getBy(Habitat.java:1056)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByType(Habitat.java:1037)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getComponentInjectValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:159)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:90)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:143)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:93)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getBy(Habitat.java:1056)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByType(Habitat.java:1037)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getComponent(Habitat.java:781)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.Lookups._getSecurityContextUtil(Lookups.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.Lookups.getSecurityContextUtil(Lookups.java:92)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecClientRequestInterceptor.<init>(SecClientRequestInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.appclient.AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.getClientInterceptorInstance(AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.appclient.AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.createClientRequestInterceptor(AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBInitializer.post_init(GlassFishORBInitializer.java:132)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.postInitORBInitializers(PIHandlerImpl.java:915)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.initialize(PIHandlerImpl.java:265)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.postInit(ORBImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.set_parameters(ORBImpl.java:704)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.setParameters(ORBImpl.java:691)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.osgi.ORBFactory.initialize(ORBFactory.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:581)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:364)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:401)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:346)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.listBindings(SerialContext.java:866)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.listBindings(InitialContext.java:466)
    at com.apihotels.docrepo.test.DocUploaderTest.setup(DocUploaderTest.java:68)
    at com.apihotels.docrepo.test.DocUploaderTest.junitTestSetup(DocUploaderTest.java:54)
    at com.apihotels.docrepo.test.DocUploaderTest.main(DocUploaderTest.java:43)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hk2.component.ComponentException: Failed to create class com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.create(ConstructorCreator.java:71)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:80)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat$5.get(Habitat.java:703)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:188)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getArrayInjectValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:113)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:81)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:143)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/resource/ResourceException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.create(ConstructorCreator.java:65)
    ... 68 more
```

EDIT 2:

The remote interface I'm trying to access.

```
@Remote
public interface TheRemoteInterface {
   public void method1();
}


@Stateless
public class TheImpl implements TheRemoteInterface {
   // no members
   @Override
   public void method1() {
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code of the EJB being accessed?  It looks like there's an error trying to inject a resource into _something_.  Does the EJB attempting to be accessed have any resource injections?

Comment: @EdH No, there are no resources being injected into the EJB.  There's actually not much to it.  I added code to show exactly how it's defined.